# Adding method.args to ggplot stat_smooth() causes error

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I am trying this example from [*Introduction to Data Science: Data Analysis and Prediction Algorithms with R*, chapter 28](https://rafalab.github.io/dsbook/smoothing.html#beware-of-default-smoothing-parameters):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)
data("polls_2008")

polls_2008 %>% ggplot(aes(day, margin)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(span = 0.15, method.args = list(degree=1))
```

This causes the error, "Warning message: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: 'what' must be a function or character string." Removing the `method.args...` arguments results in normal operation. It seems that defining method.args as anything including an empty list causes the problem.

I am using R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06) built for Windows and ggplot2_3.3.2. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I double checked and this worked. They changed the default for method from "auto" to NULL. This still functions the same as "auto" use to without method.arg. But I think you need to tell it what method you are running so it can properly use the method.args

```
polls_2008 %>%
  ggplot(aes(day, margin)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", 
              span = 0.15, 
              method.args = list(degree=1))
```